# Background image for a section in a responsive site not displaying

Tags: html, image, css

Basically i am building a responsive site in HTML5 for the first time and to say im having a lot of trouble would be an under statement. Anyway one of the issues im stuck with at the moment is i cant figure out how to get an image i need for a banner section to display!

This is what im trying to achieve:

[image]

But i cant get the wave image to display without putting it inline which i dont want to do as it needs to be responsive!?

here's my html code so far:

```
<header>
    <h1></h1><!-- Logo -->

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OUR CUSTOMERS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PRICING</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PARTNERS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</header><!-- End of header -->

<section class="container">
    <h2 class="hidden">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <div class="banner">

        </div>

</section><!-- End of slider content -->
```

and here is the css:

```
.container {
width:auto;
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;
}

.banner {
background-image: url(../img/banner-lg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;

}
```

If anyone has any input that they think might help it would really be appreciated! I really don't understand why the background image doesn't just show up once it has been set in the css! When i had a slider in place it worked fine but as soon as i removed the slider and went for a static image instead it no longer appears>

Comment: Can you post the code with the image inline (that achieves the desired effect)?

Comment: <div class="banner">
    <img src="../img/banner-lg.jpg)" />
</div>

but this doesn't really work as the image is left aligned and repeats

Comment: @DannyW86 try with `background-size:cover`.

Answer (score 5):

Use this in html file.

```
<style type="text/css">
  body{
       background:url("image.jpg");
       background-size: cover;       /* For flexibility */
       }
</style>
```

***Note***: Put image in main folder not in images folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your banner class seems to be lacking width and height so it may be collapsing. Can you verify in the developer console of your browser?

Answer (score 0):

This post might be old, but here's answer for those who came here to get answer.

add the following lines to the `.banner` in the css style thing

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

If you want custom width you can play with the percentage, but if you want a specific width and height in PX you can do the following

```
height: 500px;
width: 1000px;
```

Change the width and height to your desired width and height.